# HTML5 input type="number" arabian number

Tags: html, input, localization

How following input, which is working fine under Firefox.

`<input type="number" value="١٢٣٤٥">`

But in Chrome/Chromium it just wipes the value.
Got `<html dir="rtl" lang="ar">`.

Any ideas?

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=694391

this bug states that it's fixed and works if interface is in arabian - but I tested it and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Seems chrome doesn't support non-decimals as value, as Firefox does.
Solution is to always use decimals as value - Chrome shows them as arabic when UI language is arabic.